# Python Kivy How to inject widgets made with Python to layout in kv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, layout, kivy, programmatically-created

I have written a python kivy application for displaying measurements. While searching stuff on kivy I stumbled on the the kivy-md (Material Design for kivy) project. I find the UI very good looking. That is why I want to inject my app into a screen of the kivy-md project.

My project is inside a folder `kivy-playground` which contains the `kivymd` files in a folder `kivymd`, the `main.py` (for starting the kivy md application), the `main.kv` file (for the layout of the kivy md application) and a `playground.py` which contains the kivy application for displaying measurements. I am using Python 3.7 with the latest version of kivy.

> **Goal**: I want to inject the Application view from `playground.py` into the main application which is started by the `main.py` such that
>   the view of the `playground.py` is displayed on the screen `page2`
>   (see `main.kv`) of the main application. I am totally lost how this
>   can be achieved and I would be happy if someone could show me on this
>   toy example how this can be achieved. It is not necessarily important that the `playground.py` stays as it is. If the problem can be solved by small changes in the `playground.py` file then this would be also a valid solution.

I tried to cook up a minimal working example. Here are the files

```
# main.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager


class MainApp(App):

    theme_cls = ThemeManager()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.bind(on_close=self.on_stop)

    def build(self):
        main_widget = Builder.load_file(
            os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "./main.kv")
        )
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'
        return main_widget

    def close_app(self, *largs):
        super(MainApp, self).stop(*largs)

    def on_pause(self):
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

here is the `main.kv`

```
# main.kv
#:kivy 1.10.1
#:import Toolbar kivymd.toolbar.Toolbar
#:import MDNavigationDrawer kivymd.navigationdrawer.MDNavigationDrawer
#:import NavigationLayout kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationLayout
#:import NavigationDrawerToolbar kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerToolbar

NavigationLayout:
    id: nav_layout
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id: nav_drawer
        NavigationDrawerToolbar:
        NavigationDrawerIconButton:
            icon: 'checkbox-blank-circle'
            text: "Page1"
            on_release: app.root.ids.scr_mngr.current = 'page1'
        NavigationDrawerIconButton:
            icon: 'checkbox-blank-circle'
            text: "Page2"
            on_release: app.root.ids.scr_mngr.current = 'page2'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        halign: "center"
        Toolbar:
            id: toolbar
            md_bg_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            background_palette: 'Primary'
            background_hue: '500'
            right_action_items: [['dots-vertical', lambda x: app.root.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
        ScreenManager:
            id: scr_mngr
            Screen:
                name: 'page1'
                Label:
                    text: "page1"
            Screen:
                name: 'page2'
                Label:
                    text: "Page 2"
```

and here is the `playground.py` which I want to inject into the screen `page2` of the main application.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class Playground(App):

    def build(self):
        hello_world_label = Label(text="Hello World!")
        return hello_world_label


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Playground().run()
```

Comment: I suspect that trying to have two Apps running in the same window would cause lots of problems. It would be much easier to just insert the root widget from your `Playground` App into the original App.

Comment: It does not have to be with a second app, but I don't know how to change the playground.py such that it can be injected into `page2` of the `main.kv`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can change `Playground.py` to something like this:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

def getPlaygroundRoot():
    hello_world_label = Label(text="Hello World!")
    return hello_world_label


class PlayGround(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PlayGround, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_widget(getPlaygroundRoot())

class Playground(App):

    def build(self):
        return getPlaygroundRoot()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Playground().run()
```

Then, in your `main.py`, you can add:

```
from playGround import getPlaygroundRoot
```

And then use `add_widget(getPlaygroundRoot())` to add the `Playground` root to some container in the `MainApp`.

Or, if you want to use `Playground` in your `.kv` file, you can add 
`#:import playground playGround` to your `.kv` file, and then add:

```
        Screen:
            name: 'page2'
            Label:
                text: "Page 2"
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0.8}
                size_hint: (1.0, 0.2)
            PlayGround:
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'y': 0.1}
                size_hint: (1.0, 0.2)
```

to add it to your `page2`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I will give this a try and accept the answer if it worked out.

Comment: Thank you! It worked like a charm! It took me some time to figure out how to refactor the application but your example was key in understanding how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

- If there is a kv file, *playground.kv* for *playground.py* then use `include <file>` in *main.kv*
- Add import statement, `from playground import PlayGround` in *main.py*

[Kivy Lang Directives » include <file>](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.lang.html#lang-directives)

> ```
> include <file>
> ```
>
> Syntax:
>
> ```
> #:include [force] <file>
> ```
>
> Includes an external kivy file. This allows you to split complex
>   widgets into their own files. If the include is forced, the file will
>   first be unloaded and then reloaded again.

## Snippets

### playground.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class PlayGround(Label):
    pass


class Playground(App):

    def build(self):
        return PlayGround()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Playground().run()
```

### playground.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0

<PlayGround>:
    text: "Hello World!"
```

### min.py

```
# main.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
from playground import PlayGround


class MainApp(App):
```

### main.kv

```
# main.kv
#:kivy 1.10.1
#:import Toolbar kivymd.toolbar.Toolbar
#:import MDNavigationDrawer kivymd.navigationdrawer.MDNavigationDrawer
#:import NavigationLayout kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationLayout
#:import NavigationDrawerToolbar kivymd.navigationdrawer.NavigationDrawerToolbar

#:include playground.kv

NavigationLayout:
    ...
        ScreenManager:
            id: scr_mngr
            Screen:
                name: 'page1'
                Label:
                    text: "page1"
            Screen:
                name: 'page2'
                Label:
                    text: "Page 2"
                PlayGround:
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is, that my whole code is in python. I am not using any kv file for the `playground.py`.